# Angular 2 Reactive Forms 'pattern' validator not working

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I have defined the following validation:

```
            Validators.pattern("/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]$/")]]
```

Its to validate postal codes, but when I enter the string 'K1K1A1' the validator says its invalid.

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Try to remove the `quotes`.

Comment: *postal codes* isn't helpful. Which country postal codes? What is a valid postal code in your case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Validators.pattern()` looks like:

```
if (typeof pattern === 'string') {
  regexStr = `^${pattern}$`;
  regex = new RegExp(regexStr);
} else {
  regexStr = pattern.toString();
  regex = pattern;
}
```

So, just remove slashes and `^$` characters to fit with angular.
Or you also remove quotes and javascript will take your expression as a RegExp type.

Comment: Yes, removing quotes the typeof is equals RegExp.

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091334/password-validation-is-not-working-in-angular-5 @Serginho